# Disabling Animation After The Button Is Pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

This button is a series of images that animate a glowing effect, when the button is pressed I'd like the animation to stop:

```
[self.buttonHintdisabled setBackgroundImage: [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"c" duration:3.0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

How is this done?

If there is another way to do this in code that could disable it when the button is pressed, please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this on a `UIButton`, but I will give you an idea how I would do it:

Often times we set a `target` with our `UIButton`:

```
[self.buttonHintdisabled addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Within `buttonPressed:`, we would carry out what we would like to do when the button is pressed.

So, with that in mind, in addition to what you would like to do within `buttonPressed`, you could try:

```
[self.buttonHintdisabled setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"c0.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Once the action within that method is done, set it back using what you have above:

```
[self.buttonHintdisabled setBackgroundImage:[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"c" duration:3.0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Im thinking of replacing it completely... Is this what i'm about to do acceptable: I will setHidden when the button that animates is pressed and then I'll replace it with a grayed out uiimage of the same picture?

Comment: @Jelter Sure, but setting the button hidden would hide the button so that when you replace it with a grayed out image, it would not show; instead I would suggest setting `userInteractionEnabled = NO;` and replace it with the grayed out picture on `UIButton` and when you are done with your action, set it back to `YES` and replace it with the animation.

Comment: Check what I've done Ive created a new button outlet thats called disabledhintImage, and I've set it behind the animated button called buttonHintdisabled, when the action of clicking the button happens ive set buttonhintdisabled to setHidden, and unchecked enabled in the attributes inspector for disabledhintbutton, thus when the animated image is pressed it hides and the button underneath it is exposed as disabled.. it works well, but will I have a problem with Apple Inc & iTunes when i load my game up?

Comment: @Jelter Sounds like a good workaround to me. No, I don't see any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use selected button state (UIControlStateSelected)

add this line

```
[self.buttonHintdisabled setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

and then in its action

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
     [self.buttonHintdisabled setSelected:YES];
}
```

or if you can just replace background image in - (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender